# join querybuilder ax 2012 x++

Tags: join, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

Excuse my english (is not my native language)

Well, i wanna make this query (i make the temp table EMPL, the first temp table VEN is very easy but i don't see how to make the join)

```
SELECT 'CADORE_MP',EMPL.PERSONNELNUMBER, EMPL.NOMBRE, 0 AS CANTIDAD, VEN.MONTO  FROM 
    (
    SELECT VATNUM, SUM(INVOICEAMOUNT) AS MONTO FROM CUSTINVOICEJOUR
    WHERE INVOICEDATE>=@FECHAI and INVOICEDATE<=@FECHAF
    AND PAYMENT LIKE '%DIAS%'
    AND CUSTGROUP LIKE 'EMP%' 
    AND REVERSE_GT=0 AND TAXTYPEDOCUMENTID='FC'
    GROUP BY VATNUM) VEN
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT HW.PERSONNELNUMBER, HPIN.IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER, PRE.FIRSTNAME+' '+PRE.SECONDNAME+' '+PRE.FIRSTLASTNAME+' '+PRE.SECONDLASTNAME AS NOMBRE
    FROM HcmPersonIdentificationNumber HPIN INNER JOIN HCMWORKER HW ON HPIN.PERSON=HW.PERSON AND HPIN.IDENTIFICATIONTYPE=5637146829
    INNER JOIN PAYROLLEMPL PRE ON HW.PERSON=PRE.PERSON
    INNER JOIN HCMEMPLOYMENT HE ON HW.RECID=HE.WORKER
    LEFT JOIN PAYROLLLIQUIDATION PL ON HW.PERSONNELNUMBER=PL.EMPLID AND PL.DATELOW<@FECHAF
    LEFT JOIN PAYROLLGROUPEMPLOYEES PRGE ON HW.PERSONNELNUMBER=PRGE.EMPLID AND GROUPSEMPLYEESID='CADORE_PQ'
    WHERE HE.VALIDTO>='21541231' AND PL.EMPLID IS NULL AND PRGE.EMPLID IS NULL) EMPL ON VEN.VATNUM=EMPL.IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER
```

it have some parameters and other are constants.

so, i can do the two inner selects but later i can't do the join of this two temp tables

and i wanna know if someone can explain me the diference of join, exists join, no exists join. something like this

[image]

and if is posible to make when only wanna data from A but do not intersect with B

This is what i have

```
Query query;    
QueryRun Run;
QueryBuildDataSource dataSourceHW;
QueryBuildDataSource dataSourceHPIN;
QueryBuildDataSource dataSourcePRE;
QueryBuildDataSource dataSourceHE;
QueryBuildDataSource dataSourcePL;
QueryBuildDataSource dataSourcePRGE;
str textDesc = "";
date                                 FechaF;

FechaF = str2Date('21/03/2016',123);

query = new Query();

dataSourceHW = query.addDataSource(tableNum(HcmWorker));

dataSourceHPIN = dataSourceHW.addDataSource(tableNum(HcmPersonIdentificationNumber));
dataSourceHPIN.addLink(fieldNum(HcmWorker, Person), fieldNum(HcmPersonIdentificationNumber, Person));
dataSourceHPIN.addRange(fieldnum(HcmPersonIdentificationNumber,IdentificationType)).value('5637146829');
dataSourceHPIN.fetchMode(QueryFetchMode::One2One);
dataSourceHPIN.joinMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin);

dataSourcePRE = dataSourceHW.addDataSource(tableNum(PayRollEmpl), "PayRollEmpl");
dataSourcePRE.addLink(fieldNum(HcmWorker, Person), fieldNum(PayRollEmpl, Person));
dataSourcePRE.fetchMode(QueryFetchMode::One2One);
dataSourcePRE.joinMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin);

dataSourceHE = dataSourceHW.addDataSource(tableNum(HcmEmployment), "HcmEmployment");
dataSourceHE.addLink(fieldNum(HcmWorker, RecId), fieldNum(HcmEmployment, Worker));
dataSourceHE.addRange(fieldnum(HcmEmployment,ValidTo)).value(strFmt('%1' ,DateTimeUtil::maxValue()));
dataSourceHE.fetchMode(QueryFetchMode::One2One);
dataSourceHE.joinMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin);

dataSourcePL = dataSourceHW.addDataSource(tableNum(PayRollLiquidation));
dataSourcePL.addLink(fieldNum(HcmWorker, PersonnelNumber), fieldNum(PayRollLiquidation, EmplId));
dataSourcePL.addRange(fieldnum(PayRollLiquidation,DateLow)).value('21/03/2016');
dataSourcePL.fetchMode(QueryFetchMode::One2One);
dataSourcePL.joinMode(JoinMode::OuterJoin);

// this join under this dont work, indistinctly if i use it, always show me the same
// because of this i ask above about the data of table A only 

dataSourcePRGE = dataSourceHW.addDataSource(tableNum(PayRollGroupEmployees));
dataSourcePRGE.addLink(fieldNum(HcmWorker, PersonnelNumber), fieldNum(PayRollGroupEmployees, EmplId));
dataSourcePRGE.addRange(fieldnum(PayRollGroupEmployees,GroupsEmplyeesId)).value('CADORE_PQ');
//dataSourcePRGE.addRange(fieldnum(PayRollGroupEmployees,EmplId)).value(SysQuery::valueEmptyString());
dataSourcePRGE.fetchMode(QueryFetchMode::One2One);
dataSourcePRGE.joinMode(JoinMode::NoExistsJoin);
```

will thanks you if someone help me

Comment: "...only wanna data from A but do not intersect with B..." search for [notExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa656402.aspx).  JoinMode::NoExistsJoin

Comment: Try to build up the query one data source at a time starting with `HcmWorker` not exists joined to `PayRollGroupEmployees`. Check your results after each data source that you add. AX sometimes has problems when different join types are used in the same query.

Comment: Well in the end something similar made, i made the query of custinvoicejour and then for each recordset of this make a query with the range of vatnum in the query i post above, i know is not efficient but it works and is a report that only use one time at month